# Web browser Text annotator to annotate documents

Tags: javascript, html, annotations, ckeditor

I thought to bounce this idea from people here:

I have to build a light-weight text annotator which will be later embedded in one of website.
The text annotator will be used to collect manual annotation for various documents from various users (i.e. human users which are logged in to that website). User will be rewarded based on their labor.

Wondering if anyone has already done similar thing or if someone has any thought on this task.

As per my research so far, somehow using [CKeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for this seems good idea.

This is totally new to me and I am also new to JavaScript (but hardcore with Java core :) ). Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The Firefox addon [Semantic Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/semantic-checker/) retrieves semantic data such as this from websites. There are also several JavaScript libraries which facilitate creation of such metadata:

- [RDFaCE](http://aksw.org/Projects/RDFaCE.html)
- [createjs](http://createjs.org/)
- [annotate.js](https://github.com/szabyg/annotate.js)
- [alohaeditor with WAI plugin](http://aloha-editor.org/builds/development/latest/doc/guides/output/plugin_wai-lang.html)
- [vie.js with backbone.js](https://github.com/tHerrmann/VIE)

**References**

- [Commercial Benefits of Accessibility | CKEditor.com](http://ckeditor.com/blog/Commercial-Benefits-of-Accessibility)